# jquery load json when document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i confuse why my this simple code is wrong.

i just want to list json data in select when document is load. 
this is my jquery code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#choose").load(function(event){
            $.getJSON('data/colors.json', function(jd) {
                $('#choose').html('<option value="' + jd.name'">' + jd.name + '</option>');
                $('#choose').append('<option value="' + jd.name'">' + jd.name + '</option>');
            });
        });
   });
</script>
```

this is my html :

```
<select id="choose" style="width:200px">

   </select>
```

and last this is my json file :

```
[
{
"name": "Yoza",
"age" : "22",
"sex": "male"
},
{
"name": "nayla",
"age" : "18",
"sex": "female"
}
]
```

how to load that json with each. so i can load more than that data.

Comment: select elements don't have a load event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(jd) {
        $.each(jd, function(i, v){
            $('#choose').append('<option value="' + v.name + '">' + v.name + '</option>');
        })
    })

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/z5QQOBPvvcIC4ULs9qsJ?p=preview)

Comment: Hey, it works. thanks very much. but how to make that json load when page is load?

Comment: what do you mean by pageload

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      var data = [];

    $.getJSON( 'data/colors.json', function( jd ) {

          $.each( jd, function( k,v ){

              data.push('<option value="' + v.name'">' + v.name + '</option>');

             });
            $('#choose').append( data.join('') );
        });
```

Comment: $.getJSON is asynch by default, so you have to put $('#choose').append( data.join('') ); just after the each loop but still inside getJSON callback function. Finally, why use data?

Answer (score 0):

why do you wait for `$('#choose')` to be loading ? Your function is executed when `document` is ready, so `$('#choose')` is ready too.